# Why do I get a different Laurent series than Taylor series?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

**Exercise**: Determine the taylor series of $f(z)=\frac 2 {z^2-1}$ around the point $z_0 \in \mathbb C -\{\pm 1\}$.

**My attempt:**
We have
$$\frac 2 {(z+1)(z-1)}=\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac 1 {z+1}$$

Now, suppose we have $|z|<1$. Then, using the geometric series:
$$...=-\frac1{1-z}-\frac 1{1-(-z)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)z^k + \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)(-z)^k$$
So in the Taylor series, we have the coefficients: $a_n$ is $-2$ for $n$ even, otherwise $0$.

However, for $|z|>1$, we get:
$$...=\frac 1 z \frac 1 {1-\frac 1 z}-\frac 1 z \frac 1 {1-(-\frac 1 z)}$$

Now I want to use geometric series again, but I would get only coefficients for $(1/z)^n$, so I would get a Laurent series with non trivial principal part.

So a different result than before, and the exercise only asks for a Taylor series.

---

I am confused. What's the matter here?!

Comment: Both series are correct but have different regions of convergence. The Taylor series converges within the unit disk, and the Laurent series converges outside.

Comment: Also, note that the question asks for the Taylor series around an arbitrary center $z_0 \in \Bbb C \setminus \{\pm 1\}$, but the Taylor series that you've written is specifically centered at $0$.

Comment: Well, I wrote up a super-complicated answer (that you can see below) before I remembered the basic fact that the Taylor series is $\sum f^{(n)}(z_0)(z-z_0)^n/n!$, and for both of your functions $\frac{1}{z-1}$ and $\frac{1}{z+1}$ it's super-easy to compute the $n$-th derivative explicitly. D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

BenGrossman's comments answer the question posed in your title and your work, but like he said, that's expanding around $z_0 = 0$.

To answer the exercise you need to get these written as sums with powers of $(z-z_0)$, and you do that by seeing the following dirty, filthy trick once, and being able to pull it out of your back pocket the next time someone asks for it. I'll do it for $\frac{1}{z-1}$, and let you handle the second term:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z-1} &= \frac{-1}{1-z_0+z_0-z}\\
&= \frac{-1}{(1-z_0)(1 - \frac{(z-z_0)}{(1-z_0)})}\\
&= \frac{-1}{1-z_0}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{z-z_0}{1-z_0}}\\
&= \frac{-1}{1-z_0}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(1-z_0)^n}\cdot(z-z_0)^n\\
\end{align}
$$
where the last step is just recognizing the sum of an infinite geometric series with ratio $\frac{z-z_0}{1-z_0}$ and writing it out as the geometric series. If you find that hard to follow, maybe think of keeping an eye on how we're getting the $(z-z_0)$ to do what we want (i.e. create a power series), and we're willing to let all kinds junk involving $z_0$ build up to do so.

Now just do a little clean-up to get it in the form $\sum a_n(z-z_0)^n$, do basically the same trick for $\frac{1}{z+1}$, and subtract the two series.

(P.S. I looked at $\frac{1}{z-1}$ and $\frac{1}{z+1}$ and though we could get away with just substituting $-z$ for $z$ in the above formula and handling the minus sign, but I don't think it'll work. That'll give you a Taylor series around $-z_0$, and that's no good for us. We just have to carry out a second derivation, and see how the change in sign affect each step. )

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series around $z_0\ne a$ of $\frac1{z-a}$ is:
$$\frac1{z-a}=\frac1{z_0-a}\;\frac1{1-\frac{z-z_0}{a-z_0}}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z-z_0)^n}{(a-z_0)^{n+1}},$$
for $|z-z_0|<|a-z_0|.$

The Laurent series is
$$\frac1{z-a}=\frac1{z-z_0}\;\frac1{1-\frac{a-z_0}{z-z_0}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a-z_0)^n}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}},$$
for $|z-z_0|>|a-z_0|.$