# Laurent series with 2 poles

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

> Determine the Laurent series expansion $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n (z + i)^n$$ of the function $$f(z) = \frac{z}{(1 + z^2)(z + i)}$$ around $-i$ in the region $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \,\,\,|\,\,\, 2 < |z + i| < 3\}.$

So I need to find the Laurent series around the point $-i$. My attempt was to use partial fraction decomposition, but I fail to do that. My equations always yield errors.

I noticed it has a pole of degree two at $i$ and a simple pole at $-i$. I am able to caluclate the residues of them, but would that help me in any way...?

I'm completely stuck on this for hours. Can someone help me?

Comment: The residues could help you compute the partial fraction decomposition. You should find that
$$
f(z) = \frac{i}{4(z + i)} + \frac{1}{2(z + i)^2} - \frac{i}{4(z - i)}
$$

Comment: Can you show your calculations with partial fractions? That approach should work. It might also help to notice that you are asked for a power series in $(z+i)$ and $f(z) = (z+i)^{-2}.(z/(z-i))$, so that you really only need to find the power series in $(z+i)$ for $z/(z-i)$

Comment: @krm2233 Don't presume to know what the question was. In the question as originally posted, $z_0$ was taken to be an arbitrary element of the set $\{2 < |z + i| < 3\}$.

Comment: @mathematics The question as you originally asked it is looking for a Laurent series centered at an unspecified $z_0 \in \{z \in \mathbb{C} \,\,\,|\,\,\, 2 < |z + i| < 3\}.$ Is there a reason that you're specifically asking about the case that $z_0 = -i$?

Comment: @mathematics This is the same thing that you did [in this previous question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4772717/81360). Is there a reason that you're not answering these questions as written?

Comment: @BenGrossmann: are you sure? The question, as it stands now, does not make sense: 
 $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} a_n(z+i)^n$ is not a Laurent series about $z_0$, and for $z_0 \in \{2<|z+i|<3\}$, and the annulus in which the Laurent expansion $f(z)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} a_n (z-z_0)^n$ is required to be valid in is not specified. I do not think it is reasonable to interpret the question to be asking for 3 expansions, one each in $A_1 = \{0<|z-z_0|<m_1\}$, $A_2=\{m_1<|z-z_0|<m_2\}$ and $A_3=\{|z-z_0|>m_2\}$, where $m_1 = \min\{|z_0-i|,|z_0+i|\}$, $m_2 = \max\{|z_0-i|,|z_0+i|\}$.

Comment: @krm2233 I am sure that the question was originally written in this way, and I agree that it currently doesn't make sense, but I'm not sure about the intent behind the question. Unfortunately, the asker hasn't clarified what's going on here.

Comment: Sorry! I noticed I had an error in the question. I am supposed to find the Laurent series around $-i$ in the given region. I edited the question!

Comment: Let $z=-i+u.$ Using [the Laurent series (around $u_0=0$) of $\frac1{u-a}$ for $|u|>a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4773024)
$$f(z)=\frac{-i+u}{u^2}\frac1{u-2i}=(-i+u)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2i)^n}{u^{n+3}}=\dots$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f(z)}&=\frac{z}{\left(1+z^2\right)(z+i)}\\
&\color{blue}{=\frac{i}{4(z+i)}+\frac{1}{2(z+i)^2}-\frac{i}{4(z-i)}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

$f$ has a pole of order $2$ at $z=-i$ and a simple pole at $z=+i$. We have to distinguish two regions of convergence when expanding around $z=-i$:
\begin{align*}
D_1:&\quad 0<  |z+i|<2\\
D_2:&\quad  |z+i|>2
 \end{align*}

- The  region $D_1$ is a punctured disc with center $z=-i$, radius $2$ and the pole at $z=i$ at the boundary of the disc. It admits for the fraction with pole  at $z=-i$ a representation as principal part of a Laurent series and for the fraction with pole at $z=i$ a power series.
- The region $D_2$ contains all points outside the disc with center $z=-i$ and radius $2$. It admits for all fractions a representation as principal part of a Laurent series.

Since the region of consideration is $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \,|\,\,\, 2 < |z + i| < 3\}$ we consider the expansion of $f$ as Laurent series in $D_2$.

> We obtain from (1)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f(z)}&= \frac{i}{4(z+i)}+\frac{1}{2(z+i)^2}-\frac{i}{4(z-i)}\\
> &=\frac{i}{4(z+i)}+\frac{1}{2(z+i)^2}-\frac{i}{4(z+i-2i)}\\
> &=\frac{i}{4(z+i)}+\frac{1}{2(z+i)^2}-\frac{i}{4(z+i)}\,\frac{1}{1-\frac{2i}{z+i}}\\
> &=\frac{i}{4(z+i)}+\frac{1}{2(z+i)^2}-\frac{i}{4(z+i)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2i)^n}{(z+i)^n}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2(z+i)^2}-\frac{i}{4(z+i)}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2i)^n}{(z+i)^n}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}-\frac{i}{4(z+i)}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(2i)^n}{(z+i)^n}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}-\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{(2i)^n}{(z+i)^n}}
> \end{align*}